# How to bind TextBlock Tool Tip's from a List generated by an Enum?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to do something that I am finding to be a little complicated in MVVM / WPF. I have a `ComboBox` that I am binding the `ItemsSource` to a List. The List has 5 elements of Strings that look like this:

```
 "Dog"
 "Cat"
 "Lizard"
 "Fish"
 "Hamster"
```

I would like the Tool Tip to be using this List here:

```
 "Golden Retriever"
 "Bombay"
 "Spotted"
 "Goldfish"
 "Wide-Toothed"
```

So that when I hover over Dog, the Tool Tip is *"Golden Retriever"* and so forth. The problem is, I can't seem to bind to figure out the binding.

```
<ComboBox Name="PetCB" ItemsSource="{Binding Pet.PetList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Pet.SelectedPet}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=PetCB, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                       ToolTip="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Right now, I am just binding the `ToolTip` to the List again.

My List for the Pet Details is

```
List<string> PetDetails = new List<string>();
```

I think the main problem is that the List being generated is from an `Enum` and not an actual class. If it were a Class, I could just have two properties and bind to those properties but that's not the case here. I can't change the structure at this time, unfortunately. This would be a simple question had I could.

Comment: How does your Pet class look like?

Comment: It doesn't do much, it just initializes the PetList List and add the values of the Enum via the constructor.

Comment: how do you get from for example "dog" to "Golden Retriever"

Comment: They are separate Lists. A Golden Retriever is a type of dog, I am trying to use the List of PetDetails as the Tool Tip for the PetList.

Comment: Use a Binding Converter with a Dictionary<string, string> that maps from pet breed to tooltip.

Comment: how do you want to link the two, i.e. siginify that dog and golden retriever are suppose to be together?  Anything against creating a custom object/class/struct to contain both type and detail i.e. have pet.PetList = List<PetDetail>()? rather then just a string.

Comment: Thanks, @Clemens. That worked.

Comment: Perhaps this is just an example, but aren't your items and tooltips reversed?  I would think you'd display "Golden Retriever," and if someone doesn't know what that is, you'd help them out with "Dog."  All golden retrievers are dogs, but not all dogs are golden retrievers...